# Run terminal commands within deployment file

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, deployment

I wanted to run an application called rstudio package manager. It has some terminal commands to be run after the deployment. Is there any way to add those commands within the deployment file? I tried this way and I am getting crashloopback error. I am entirely new to writing the deployment file. Am I doing anything wrong or messing up with syntax?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rspm-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rspm
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rspm
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: nckaoepekin.local
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: RSPM_LICENSE
          value: my_license_key
        image: rstudio/rstudio-package-manager:latest
        name: rstudio-package-manager
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'; rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'; rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran; rspm sync"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4242
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rstudio-pm
spec:
  selector:
    app: rspm
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 4242
    targetPort: 4242
    nodePort: 31010
  type: NodePort
```

I want to add these terminal commands (Specified above also)

```
alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'
rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'
rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran
rspm sync
```

When I remove command and args specified, the deployment file is working. But when I add the command and args, I am getting crashloopback error. Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do these command need to run after the container starts running ?

Comment: Yes, thats right. These commands needs to be executed after the pod is running @tarunkhosla . I can always get into the pod and run these commands.  But is there any other way to automate these steps?

Comment: also check the logs before the pod state is CrashLoopBackoff  , that will show what is missing or what command is not recognized.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers

Try using the postHandler from above link. @Siddharth

Comment: Can postHandler used in Deployment rather than as a Pod? It throws me error while applying it as pod.

Comment: yes ,  can be applied as it is applied to the container.

Comment: I tried postHandler. It worked for one command. When I define al the four - "alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'; rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'; rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran; rspm sync" it is getting failed. @tarunkhosla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218214/discussion-between-tarun-khosla-and-siddharth).

Comment: Perhaps ask the question with support at Rstudio, or at community.rstudio.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added sleep after all my bash commands since those files were taking time to execute.

```
            exec:
              command:
                - "sh"
                - "-c"
                - |
                  alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm' &&
                  sleep 5 &&
                  rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages' &&
                  sleep 5 &&
                  rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran &&
                  sleep 5 &&
                  rspm sync
```

And it got worked!

Answer (score 2):

You can use poststart hook [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/)

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command:
        - "sh"
        - "-c"
        - |
          alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm' &&
          rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'&&
          rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran &&
          rspm sync
```

Comment: it's good that you have found the issue. Additionally in order not to wait each time the pod is restarted it is possible to use "initContainers" https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/ ; however, you might need adjusting your app architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `postStart` container lifecycle event as show [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/)

#### Edit

1. Create & store file in container image

```
cat > postStart.sh <<
alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'
rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'
rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran
rspm sync
EOF
```

2. Try running postStart hook like below

```
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - postStart.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that and I am getting error. This is my postStart looks like--> 


lifecycle:
postStart:
exec:
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'; rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'; rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran; rspm sync"]

And I am getting this error
PostStartHookError: command 'sh -c alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'
rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'
rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran

Comment: @Siddharth Check Edit section. Need not to mention but still; remove `command:` and `args:` from containers section template.

Comment: Tried, still not working. Only the alias part is working. The rest is not working